# different results for SimpleDateFormat in local and live environments

Tags: java, date

I have the following code

```
public String getDate(Date date) throws Exception{

        String finalDate = "";

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        finalDate = formatter.format(date);

        return finalDate;

}
```

I passed the input for this method as `9999-12-30 18:30:00.0`.

In my live environment the result is :`12/30/9999`

In my local environment the result is :`12/31/9999`

What might be the reason for this strange behaviour. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Probably a time zone problem, you should try to give the `Locale` when you create the `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: You're looking for bugs that could only happen in 7986 years? `;)`

Comment: What are the main differences between your local and live environment? OS, server, ...

Comment: @StijnGeukens my local is in india.and live is in US.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there is a timezone difference between your live environment and local

Comment: what i need to do now

Comment: Or set timezone on both environment to one or code to use some specific timezone in your code.

Comment: @PSR you should set the timezone to the formatter with the timezone of your live environment

Answer (score 1):

To force your dateformat to use a specific time zone, for example UTC, you can use:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

@psr as you mentioned that your local server is in India and production is in US.

The timezone is the issue so it is creating this problem.

Since your production server is in US, try this.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

Answer (score 0):

One good thing to keep in mind is that `java.util.Date` does not have a notion of time zone in it. I'm always surprised how few people know that. So if you want unified results in your application, make sure you use timezone when you parse and when you print.

As @assylias said, you can set timezone of date formatter to achieve this.

Comment: Also be careful when reading from or writing to date fields in Oracle: http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.com/2013/05/how-to-read-dates-from-oracle-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Time zone format for sure. I would recommend you instead of using SimpleDateFormat use JodaTime.

Also if you want prevent time zone problem for all environments  formatter.setTimeZone("UTC")